# Picking a Python Interpreter in VS Code when using Docker and poetry

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, python-poetry

I open a monorepo folder within VS Code where the top folders are different services. One of the services is a python service using poetry to install dependencies.

I am using poetry's `in-project=true` `virtualenv` setting so that all dependencies are actually stored in `./python-service/.venv`.

The monorepo can be run locally using a docker-compose file. Consequently, any dependency installation is done on the container.

VS Code does not automatically detect this virtual environment, but when manually set, it errors immediately:

```
Linter 'flake8' is not installed. Please install it or select another linter".
Error: spawn /Users/me/dev/project/python-service/.venv/bin/python EACCES
```

If I look at the `./python-service/.venv/bin/python` file, I can see it's actually a symlink pointing at `/usr/local/bin/python` which does not exist on my machine, only on the container.

Since VS Code is running on my machine, not the container, it makes sense that it cannot follow this symlink.

I have considered two options:

1. Use poetry's `always-copy` `virtualenv` option. For some reason this does not actually copy the `python` binary ([replicated by someone else](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/discussions/7323)). So this doesn't actually resolve this problem.
2. Dev containers plugin for VS Code. While this works in theory, having to open a new window for each python service seems cumbersome. Ideally VS Code is able to use the appropriate venv as necessary.

What is the correct way to configure poetry/vscode/docker to ensure an interpreter can be set in VS Code?

Comment: A virtual environment is specific to a Python installation; the host and container can't share a virtual environment, and you probably need to avoid bind-mounting a host virtual environment into a container.  From what you're describing it seems like you're trying to run a tool on the host against code that lives on the host from an IDE on the host; it doesn't seem like you need Docker for this.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze. To clear up any confusion, I'm not using Docker to solve this problem. Docker is just how this service happens to be running. I am not bind-mounting a host virtual environment to the container, it is the other way around. The container has a virtual environment that I would like to use on the host (via my editor's interpreter). My naive understanding of these virtual environments are they should contain all dependencies/binaries required to run any tooling on top of it. Is that not true?

Comment: That is not true.  The most important thing you note already is that the `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python` is a symbolic link to the "real" Python, and the host can't access the container's `/usr/local/bin/python` at all.  Some C-based extensions can also depend on very specific details of the Python interpreter, so you can't necessarily use this virtual environment with the host's `python` even if the path was correct.

Comment: Ah yes, we are on the same page. But I don't think VS Code attempts to use the host's python binary, it is trying to use the container's python binary. An example of the failing command: `./python-service/.venv/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.1/pythonFiles/linter.py -m flake8 ./python-service/file.py`. In this case, if the file was a copy of the binary (rather than a symlink) it would have worked as expected (I think). Which is why I tried the copy option. I believe there is another flag for virtualenvs `--copies` that would work, but poetry doesn't seem to support it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the idea that I can think off:-

Assumptions:

- dev env with python:3.XX-slim-bullseye
- global `python` version remains same for all the services
- `make` and `poetry` is installed globally

I would make use of `makefile` or `bash script`

```
venvs: service1 service2

service1_venv:
    poetry install -C service1
service2_venv:
    poetry install -C service2
```

Trigger `make venvs` as `postCreateCommand` in `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json` file to install all the venv of services

I haven't tried it, Ideally should work with few workarounds